# How to rename image or add random number to the image to make unique name

Tags: php, image, rename

```
$target = "upload/";

$targetx = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $targetx))
{

}
else {
}

$targetx = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $targetx))
{

}
else {

}

$targetx = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'], $targetx))
{

}
else {

}

$targetx = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'], $targetx))
{

}
else {

echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
$photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$photo2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$photo3=($_FILES['photo3']['name']);
$photo4=($_FILES['photo4']['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for each file:

```
$file = $_FILES['photo1']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$photo = "newfile_".time().rand(5, 15).".".$ext
$targetx = $target . $photo;
```

Comment: then what change with  this line     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $targetx))

Comment: try updated code.. no need to change in if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $targetx))

Answer (score 0):

Why ont using the timestamp? You are sure it is unique... Because what if two images have the same random sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some hash functions like md5(). Just apply this function to the name of uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

$newfilename = time().rand().".".$extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$target_Path = $path_to_image_directory.basename($_FILES['url']['name']);
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)|(jpeg)|(gif)|(png)$/', strtolower ($_FILES['url']['name']))) {
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['url']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );
}
$extention = explode(".",$_FILES['url']['name']); // Or use str function

################### end code for move  #############################

$name = $imageName. "-" . RAND(10,100) . "." . $extention[1] ;

#####################################renaming the file ################
rename($path_to_image_directory.basename($_FILES['url']['name']), $path_to_image_directory.$name  );
```